# Add git folder add not working - getting white arrow

Tags: git, github, git-push

I have read some of the other posts on stackoverflow and realize the problem, however, how do I fix this? I tried: `git rm --cached client_folder` but i get the folllowing error msg: I have this same problem:

```
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /Users/user/Desktop/final-8/.git/
User@User final-8 % git add client
warning: adding embedded git repository: client
hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of
hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
hint: If you meant to add a submodule, use:
hint: 
hint:   git submodule add <url> client
hint: 
hint: If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the
hint: index with:
hint: 
hint:   git rm --cached client
hint: 
hint: See "git help submodule" for more information.
```

how do I fix this? I tried: `git rm --cached client_folder` but go the folllowing error msg:

```
git rm --cached client

error: the following file has staged content different from both the
file and the HEAD:
    client
(use -f to force removal)
```

---

[edit] I ran `git rm --cached -f client` and this is what i got:

```
User final-8 % git rm --cached -f client 
**rm 'client'** 
User final-8 % git init 
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /Users//Desktop/final-8/.git/ 
User final-8 % git add client 
warning: adding embedded git repository: client 
hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository. hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
```

I tried again and now I am getting:

```
client % git rm --cached -f client
fatal: pathspec 'client' did not match any files
```

Comment: `client` is already a (separate) Git repository. You cannot add a repository to a repository; if you ask Git to do so, you get the above warning, and instead, Git adds a *link* (a so-called *gitlink*) *to* that repository, rather than actually adding the repository. That's the arrow you're seeing: a gitlink. If you don't want a gitlink, don't use a (sub)repository: copy all the useful files *out* of the (sub)repository to somewhere that's *not* a repository.

Comment: If you *do* want a gitlink, you should follow the advice Git gives, to use `git submodule add`, so that Git will not only add the gitlink itself, but also all the rest of the stuff required to make the submodule work.

Comment: @torek thank you. I just saw this now. So how do I push my files in my client folder up to github then?

Comment: I managed to remove the client folder and I deleted a .gitignore file that was in my client folder and re-added the client folder to my local repo then to github. That worked. Thank you for your hellp.

Comment: It's good that you got what you wanted to get, but remember: Git is not about *files*, it's about *commits*. Commits contain files (and, with submodules, a commit contains one or more gitlinks as well), and when you `git push` you're sending the *commits* rather than the files. (Of course the commits *contain* the files, so they come along for the ride, but keep in mind that it's always based on commits. You either get a whole commit, or none of it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line is actually an indication to turn the `-f` option on on your `git rm` command :

```
git rm --cached -f client
```

Comment: not really readable in a comment : can you add this to the body of your question ?

Comment: I don't get the point of your edit ? the prompt in your last command reads `client %`, did you `cd client` before running the command ?

Comment: Yes, cd client then git rm --cached -f client

Comment: you don't have a `client` item there, do you ?

Comment: there is a client item in my project folder "final-8". There is also a gitignore file.

Comment: I mean : I don't understand what you intend to do. You don't have a `client/client` folder, do you ? if you cd into `client`, `git rm client` won't work (and that is expected). If you stay in your root directory, `git rm --cached -f client` will work. Is there something I'm missing ?

Comment: Hi. So I ran from my root directory: MacBook-Pro final-8 % git rm --cached -f client
and got the following error: fatal: pathspec 'client' did not match any files

Comment: It looks like we are drifting off the original question. From your edit : you willingly re-added `client`, you ran other actions (not mentioned in your question) and now you have errors which seem to indicate that this folder is not tracked anymore, or has been deleted or renamed on disk. For this second set of actions, please do the basic steps to check what is in your repo : check what files and folders are there (`ls` in terminal, or open a finder window), etc ... but that's basic support, not git guidance anymore.

Comment: hi. So first: I had this error: warning: adding embedded git repository: client. 2) I so i did this: % git rm --cached -f client which returned: **rm 'client'**. So I am assuming that ""client"" was removed from my .git. Then i was trying to push my "cllient"" folder up to git with  "git add client". Is this wrong?

Comment: I managed to remove the client folder and I deleted a .gitignore file that was in my client folder and re-added the client folder to my local repo then to github. That worked. Thank you for your hellp.